# How to query different databases using CreateSqlQuery in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, informix

I have the following code:

```
Query query = this.getSession().createSqlQuery("select * from db@server:table where 1=1");
List list = query.list();
```

which throws this error:

> org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set:
>   [table] [select * from db@server:table where 1=1]

It seems that `:` is considered as a parameter prefix.
How can I query between different databases? Currently, the db I'm using is `informix11`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should have a different Hibernate `Session Factory` producing different sessions for each Data Base you have.

You can't have one session connected to several Data bases.